# Customize the InputType in EditText android

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` field in my layout, with the `android:inputType="number"`. The thing that bothers me is that in the bottom right corner, there is a button saying `next`, is it possible to customize this to have an `Done` button here instead which will trigger the keyboard to "go away"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the **android:imeOptions** attribute equal to `actionDone` for Relative EditText  as:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edittxt_done"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter text"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    />
```

Answer (score 3):

in your xml file put `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` to `EditText`

Answer (score 2):

In your EditText properties set `android:imeOptions` attribute

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

or android:imeOptions in xml file